# Proving that a subset $S$ of $N$ satisfies $S=N$ under given conditions.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let S be a subset of $\mathbb N$ such that:

**(i)**: $2^k\in S\space \forall\space  k\in \mathbb N$

**(ii)**:$k\in S,\space k\geq 2\Rightarrow k-1\in S$

Prove that $S=\mathbb N$

Now I have approached it in this way:

Let us assume that $S\neq \mathbb N$, then $\mathbb N\setminus S\neq \phi$

$\therefore$ By well ordering principle, there exists a $m\in \mathbb N\setminus S$ such that $m\leq x\space \forall\space x\in \mathbb N\setminus S$.

Now since $2^1=2\in S,\space m>2$
$$m<2^m\Rightarrow2^m>2$$
but $m\in \mathbb N\setminus S$ or $m\in \mathbb N$

$\therefore 2^m\in S$ by condition **(i)**

Now by condition **(ii)**, we can imply that $2^m-1\in S$ and since $2^m-1\in S$ and $2^m-1>2$, we can imply that $2^m-2\in S$ and so on.

Using this argument we reach to a stage when $2^m-(2^m-m)\in S\Rightarrow m\in S$ which contradicts our statement that $m\in \mathbb N\setminus S$

$\therefore$ our assumption must be incorrect which implies that $S=\mathbb N$

Please check for any conceptual mistake in this proof (I am somewhat new to well ordering principle and mathematical induction).

Also I feel that this proof is a bit long, so please provide any alternate proof if possible.

***Thanks***

Comment: It seems fine to me. For a shorter proof, note that the two conditions imply that, for every $k$, the set $\{1,...,2^{k}\}$ is contained in $S$. The union of all such sets is $\mathbb{N}$, because $(2^{k})$ is an increasing sequence of integers.

Comment: That seems much shorter and better. Actually I was required to use well ordering principle. Anyways, thanks a lot

Comment: The standard notation for the relative complement is the backslash $\setminus$ (LaTex code `\setminus`), not the slash $/$. The slash usually means a quotient set, so it might be confusing.

Comment: @HanulJeon I'm sorry. Corrected it.

Comment: You do not need to say sorry. Use a wrong notation is not wrongdoing or sin. I just want to inform you.